# MySQL calculate percent of total in a group_by / where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and would like to calculate a percentage of edited posts for a user during a specific time.

Normally, I'd do this as two separate queries but I'm pretty sure could be done with a single query. I have a group of users who have edited posts and would like to get a count of the number of edited posts per user. Like so:

```
select count(*) as edited_post_count, 
       user_id 
from posts 
where edited_at between '2022-05-31' and '2022-06-06' 
group by user_id 
order by edited_post_count desc;
```

Now, I'd like to figure out the total number of posts they have all-time to be able to say 10 of 80 posts were edited during this time. edited_at would be null if they haven't edited (and yes should be last_edited_at). How could I add this to this query?

**posts**

| id | body | user_id | edited_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "what" | 1 | 2022-06-01 |
| 2 | "ever" | 1 | NULL |
| 3 | "more" | 2 | 2022-06-03 |

Comment: Calculate total value in subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` to output the `COUNT` of posts grouped by individual users within your date range concatenated with a subquery that gets the total posts where `edited_at IS NOT NULL` and the date range is not specified.

```
select 
  count(*) as edited_post_count,
  CONCAT(count(*), ' of ',  (SELECT COUNT(*) from posts a where a.user_id = b.user_id and edited_at is not null), ' posts were edited during this time.') as total_post_count,
  user_id 
from posts b 
where edited_at between '2022-05-31' and '2022-06-06' 
group by user_id 
order by edited_post_count desc;
```

**Example Result:**

| edited_post_count | total_post_count | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 of 5 posts were edited during this time. | 1 |
| 2 | 2 of 3 posts were edited during this time. | 2 |

If you want it as a %, divide your *individual* count by your *total* count multiplied by 100.

```
  (count(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) from posts a where a.user_id = b.user_id and edited_at is not null))*100 as total_post_count_percent,
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b16f79cc64bc536e013904c66154bf88).